Angular / Material Dailogs, what is the preferred UX method for launching loading spinners over dialogs?
From UX point of view, should you load loading spinners/ progress spinner over the modal/dialogs -
i.e like so:
or should you close the dialog and then show the load the spinner - i.e avoiding the distraction of the background dialog.
This of course is 3rd level dialog.

I think it’s important to show within the modal/dialog that the process occurring is loading. There are various designs for this, including showing a spinner directly on the button.
Closing the modal/dialog and only then showing a loading indicator gives the impression that the system or page has stopped working, which can create anxiety for the user.
There are several strategies for using loading indicators. If you have any doubts, see this article: https://sujeitoprogramador.com/quando-usar-spinners-e-progress-bar-para-loading/

Thank you for this, so loading the loading spinner over dialog is a correct pattern from UX point of view to the user, i.e avoiding that anxiety.
